# Unable to POST data to Web API using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've reviewed several examples and articles here and can't seem to figure out why I can't successfully pass data to my Web API using the AJAX below.  My Web API works when I use the Swagger UI.

AJAX:

```
function sendMessage(message) {
$.ajax({
    url: apiAppUri + "/api/createmessage",
    type: "POST",
    data: {fileId: "123"},
    contentType: "application/json",
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert("Message Sent");
    }
```

})

Web API / C#

```
       [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/CreateMessage")]
    public void CreateMessage([FromBody]string fileId)
    {
        DataContainer container = new DataContainer();
        container.SendQueueMessage(fileId);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Ajax call:

```
function sendMessage(message) {
    $.ajax({
        url: apiAppUri + "/api/createmessage",
        type: "POST",
        data: {fileId: "123"},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("Message Sent");
        }
    });
}
```

API Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/createmessage")]
public void CreateMessage(string fileId)
{
    DataContainer container = new DataContainer();
    container.SendQueueMessage(fileId);
}
```